# h3 Click event (location.href) not happening

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a h3 and I want that on click the user gets delivered to another site. I know it's easy, but in my case it does not work.

```html
<h3 class="firma">Bla Bla Bla © </h3>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".firma", function() {
  location.href = "some Location";
})
```

Comment: Assuming you've included jQuery.js in the page correctly, and are running your code after the DOM is ready then your code will work fine. Check the console for errors and move your JS code just before `</body>`

Comment: What happens instead? Is there anything in the console? Were you able to debug whether the selector actually finds the `h3`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have included the Jquery correctly (before the closing body). My Console does not give me any errors.

Comment: In which case you've most likely put the jQuery code in the wrong place, or are missing the document.ready handler around it

Comment: @AlexBiro how can I debug it?

Comment: @Adkoda please search for _chrome debug javascript_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to include the `jquery plugin`?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".firma", function() {
  /*location.href = "some Location";*/
  console.log('There was a click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="firma">Bla Bla Bla © </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I used jQuery CDN. Also you can reference [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com).

**HTML**

```
...
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <h3 class="firma">Bla Bla Bla © </h3>
</body>
...
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.firma', function () {
      location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
   });
});
```